# WordPress Customize panel - accessing the values

Tags: customization, theme-options

Here is the code I'm using to add the section to the Customize panel.

```
function apple_customize_register($wp_customize){
$wp_customize->add_section('apple_footer', array(
    'title'    => 'Footer',
    'priority' => 120,
));
//------ display copyright in footer
$wp_customize->add_setting('theme_options[copyright]', array(
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'       => 'option',
));
$wp_customize->add_control('theme_options[copyright]', array(
    'settings' => 'theme_options[copyright]',
    'label'    => __('Display Copyright'),
    'section'  => 'apple_footer',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'value' => '1'
));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'apple_customize_register');
```

How do I use the values in my theme. I have tryed `get_option('theme_options[copyright]')`, `get_theme_mod('theme_options[copyright]')` and many more, but all var_dump out `bool(false)`. Please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('theme_options[copyright]', array(
'default'    => '1',
'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
'type'       => 'option',
));
```

There is nothing wrong except the default value (missing). You cant use your setting till you store it a value.